# Xampp's php file is downloading, when i try to load it

Tags: php, xampp

MY OS is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS when I try to load it.I have created a small student db through phpmyadmin (i.e., mysql, mariaDB), a user end from have the details where user enters the data in the required fields like stname, stid, etc., when submit is clicked the php file should show the students in that table, but here it is downloading the file.

The PHP file is in the htdocs of xampp only.

Comment: You claim `phpmyadmin` successfully works _on that system, that server and that (virtual) host_?

Comment: One question: why would one want to use `xampp` instead of the complete and perfectly fine LAMP stack Ubuntu offers in the standard repositories?

Comment: yes phpmyadmin is working, i can open that page(localhost/phpmyadmin) and created small DB even.

Comment: actually i am new to this ubuntu linux , i want xampp to be working perfectly, and i want my project to be working with the xampp

Comment: And that phpmyadmin application is executed on the same server as that own application you implemented? This sounds to me as if you operate two separate http servers, a "normal" apache http server ("localhost") and that xampp installation.

Comment: If that is _not_ the case and phpmyadmin is executed on the same xampp installation, then obviously something with the code or the configuration of your own application is causing the issue. Then you'd have to post details about that.

Comment: actuallu i want to work with the sever application

Comment: Sorry, I cannot make any sense from that comment. What do you mean by "the server application"? Why don't you answer to the question?

Comment: yeah here it is the same server... and php code is as simple as it looks

Comment: i dont know how to give the full code here as iam new though, it seems that the same code is working with the xampp in my win sys. Then what about the configuration what it should be like by default?

Comment: I can't tell you what your configuration should look like, I can only point out that there has to be a difference currently between the configuration for the phpmyadmin application and your application, since you claim they run in the same environment (both on the same xampp server). So what is that difference? Only you can tell.

Comment: Now my phpmyadmin is not working, even the mysql database server is not running at the control panel itself. 
there it says connection error: invlalid syntax .

Apache is working fine....